# How do I append text to the begging of a NSTextView instance?

Tags: cocoa, appkit

In my macOS app, there's a `NSTextView` showing some logs. When a log is generated, I use `NSTextView.textStorage.append(NSAttributedString)` to add it to the end of the view with a new line character.

(1) I'm not sure know how to add a log to the beginning of the view.

(2) I feel each log should be a seperate element instead of a string with a new line character, should I use other ways to build this log view ?

```
class LogView: NSTextView {

    func log(text: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textStorage?.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\(text)\n", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.white]))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textStorage` inherits from `NSAttributedString` and if there is `append` there is also `insert(at:)`

```
class LogView: NSTextView {

    func log(text: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.textStorage?.insert(NSAttributedString(string: "\(text)\n", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: NSColor.white]), at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```